# mysql left join doesn't inclue ID if joined condition fails (null)

Tags: php, mysql, join, left-join

I'm trying to LEFT JOIN a table with a user table. I'm using LEFT JOIN because I still want to return users who have no entry in the joined table. This is working, however any entry that doesn't have an entry in the joined table loses their ID (uid) (which is how I'm linking the tables)

My query:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * 
FROM  `users` cu
LEFT JOIN  `product_registrations` cpr
ON cu.uid = cpr.uid';
```

People who have product registrations returns everything as they should, people without however seem to lose their uid (it appears as null in the result)

I'm really lost, any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: Are you not missing a `'` in the end before `;`?

Comment: Sorry, must've deleted it on accident while pasting here. The query is running so there's no syntax errors - I guess I'm doing something wrong though lol

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for a full outer join - a concept not directly supported in MySQL, but for which there are well-documented workarounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that's what `LEFT JOIN` dies right. If you are trying to fetch `cpr.uid` field as well it be `NULL` if no match found but you can use `COALESCE()` function to display a default value which indicate absence like

```
SELECT cu.*, COALESCE(cpr.uid, -1) 
FROM  `users` cu
LEFT JOIN  `product_registrations` cpr
ON cu.uid = cpr.uid;
```

Comment: Using your base I got everything I need using 

$sql = 'SELECT cpr.*, cu.*, COALESCE(cpr.uid, -1) 
FROM  `coffee_users` cu 
LEFT JOIN  `coffee_product_registrations` cpr 
ON cu.uid = cpr.uid 
LIMIT '.$from.', 1000 ';

Answer (score 0):

The cpr.uid should be null not the cu.uid. Look at your logic if you read cu.uid or cpr-uid and try this:

```
SELECT cu.uid as cuid
FROM  `users` cu
LEFT JOIN  `product_registrations` cpr
ON cu.uid = cpr.uid
```

In my query you shouldn't have any null values

Answer (score 0):

The cpr.uid will be null if there isn't a cpr record. Instead of just using *, add an aliased column name for cu.uid.

```
$sql = 'SELECT `users`.*, `product_registrations`.*, `users`.`uid` as user_id
FROM  `users` cu
LEFT JOIN  `product_registrations` cpr
ON cu.uid = cpr.uid';
```

Also, unless there is a specific reason not to, don't use *. Just use the fields you need.